# How to get the word on which the text classification has been made?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, bert-language-model, multilabel-classification

I am doing a multi-label text classification using a pre-trained model of BERT. Here is an example of the prediction that has been made for one sentence-
[pred_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phwu9.jpg)

I want to get those words from the sentence on which the prediction has been made. Like this one - [right_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc4ij.jpg)

If anyone has any idea, Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-Label [Text Classification](https://huggingface.co/tasks/text-classification) (first image) and [Token Classification](https://huggingface.co/tasks/token-classification) (second image) are two different tasks for each which the model needs to be specifally trained for.

The first one returns a probability for each label considering the entire sentence. The second returns such predictions for each single word in the sentence while usually considering the rest of the sentence as context.

So you can not really use the output from a Text Classifier and use it for Token Classification because the information you get is not detailed enough.

What you can and should do is train a Token Classification model, although you obviously will need token-level-annotated data to do so.